# mongodb: Is this where I should just normalize my embedded objects?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of `Parent`s that contain `EmbeddedThing`s, and each `EmbeddedThing` contains a reference to the `User` that created it.

```
UserCollection: [
  {
    _id: ObjectId(…),
    name: '…'
  },
  …
]

ParentCollection: [
  {
    _id: ObjectId(…),
      EmbeddedThings: [
      {
        _id: 1,
        userId: ObjectId(…)
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        userId: ObjectId(…)
      }
    ]
  },
  …
]
```

I soon realized that I need to get all `EmbeddedThing`s for a given user, which I managed to accomplish using map/reduce:

```
"results": [
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "value": [ `EmbeddedThing`, `EmbeddedThing`, … ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "value": [ `EmbeddedThing`, `EmbeddedThing`, … ]
  },
  …
]
```

Is this where I should really just normalize `EmbeddedThing` into its own collection, or should I still keep map/reduce to accomplish this? Some other design perhaps?

If it helps, this is for users to see their list of `EmbeddedThing`s across all `Parent`s, as opposed to for some reporting/aggregation task (which made me realize I might me doing this wrong).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To embed or not to embed: that is the question" :)

My rules are:

- embed if an embedded object has sense only in the context of parent objects. For example, `OrderItem` without an `Order` doesn't make sense.
- embed if dictated by performance requirements. It's very cheap to read full document tree (as opposed to having to make several queries and joining them programmatically).

You should look at your access patterns. If you load `ParentThing` several thousand times per second, and load `User` once a week, then map-reduce is probably a good choice. User query will be slow, but it might be ok for your application.

Yet another approach is to denormalize even more. That is, when you add an embedded thing, add it to both parent thing and user.

- Pros: queries are fast.
- Cons: Complicated code. Double amount of writes. Potential loss of sync (you update/delete in one place, but forget to do in another).

Comment: I love mongodb for its flexiblity, but really hate the "it depends" part since I have to think about extra stuff :) Since this is a brand new project, I can only guess the access pattern. Also because it's new, I'm focusing on ease of development, not on speed. Sounds like I should just stay away from denormalizing it at the moment then!